# Cloud Firestore - this document has no data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[1][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKoHX.png)i am implementing a chat system between users and doctors in flutter. The messsages are being sent and saved in firebase but the other person is not receiving the messages.

This is what is appearing in firestore.
Is "The document has no data" might be the reason that the messages are not being fetched?

[image]

No errors are being displayed in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ6cG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ5xA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCe9r.png)

Comment: That message is saying there are no fields in the document you selected.  It looks like you have a subcollection called "messages" nested underneath it.  Click that subcollection to see its. documents.  Without seeing your code, we can't tell you why it isn't working.  The console is not wrong about the contents of your database.

Comment: Hi
Actually, the documents under the messages subcollections are being saved.
Please find above some snippets of my code.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).

Answer (score 0):

As Doug commented, your `chatroom/GGGGm5B....` document doesn't have any data in it. The `messages` that is shown in your screenshot is a **subcollection** of the document, and that is **not** automatically loaded when you read the parent document (in Firestore words: read operations are shallow).

If you want to load the messages under that document, you will have to [load that subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) separately. If you're having trouble getting that to work, edit your question to show what you tried.